# What’s the best way to connect my 3/4” gas line to my 3/8” grill hose?

Tags: pipe, natural-gas

I just had a natural gas line installed in the outside wall of my house.   It has a valve and a female 3/4” connector.   My natural gas grill has a hose with a 3/8” connector.   How can I best connect these?

I saw silver male-to-male fittings going from 3/4” to 1/2”.  Big box stores didn’t have 3/4 to 3/8.  Is there such a thing?   An old guy at the store told me a need a bunch of black iron pipes strung together to achieve the reduction but couldn’t explain why.  He seemed dubious about a simple double threaded connector.   I’d rather not have 7” of lead pipe sticking straight out of the wall if I can avoid it.

My intent is to only have the gas on when using the grill and turn off the supply valve when the grill is not in use (ie most of the time)

Thoughts?

Here's the 3/4" connector (gas line) from the house w/valve:
[image]

Here's the threaded 3/8" connector for the hose on the grill:

[image]

Just found this from a company selling brewer's supplies:
[image]

The thread sizes match what I need but...  Does that mean it's OK to use for natural gas???  Doesn't mention what it's made from.  My existing connectors both seem to be brass.

Comment: what kind of connectors are on the two ends?

Comment: There are several types of fittings/threads that could be in play here (e.g. NPT, flare). We **must** see pictures of the connectors, pipes, and fittings to be able to help you.

Comment: BTW, there is a special type of gas rated teflon thread tape for natgas/propane line fittings that is yellow in colour. Do **not** use the regular stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same size gas pipe connector and hose connector.
I ended up using one adapter.
I located it on Amazon, [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B008E5CIMQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008E5CIMQ)

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Did this actually work? My grill expects 3/8" male **pipe** thread, not **flare** thread as you linked here. 3/8" flare adapters seem to be much more common than pipe thread adapters.

Answer (score 1):

This is where big box stores don’t help but plumbing and electrical specialty stores May have the correct fitting and the gas rated tape or dope.  My specialty store carry’s both the hard line adapters for pipe  1-1/4” down to 1/2”  for the flex lines, I was picking up a fitting just a few weeks ago for my son in law he said they did not have them but he went to the big box store and was ready to use several nipples and reducing adapters, I picked up the correct one for less than he paid for the mess he had cobbled together. You may be able to find it on line also. I think it was a 3/4” female pipe to male 3/8” flare fitting.  Note you should have a gas rated shutoff valve at this connection and there are 3/4 to 1/2” ball valves out there

Answer (score 0):

What brand is the grill? Weber, for example, manufactures (or has someone else manufacture) a kit that includes all the necessary connectors for hooking the gas grill to a domestic line.

Your first stop should be to contact the grill manufacturer, explain what you want to do, and see if they can provide such a kit. (And if the grill's manufactured by Weber, my first-hand experience is that they do, since I've already had that conversation with them.)

Surely you can find the appropriately-sized fittings at a specialty store and cobble together your own connection. And assuming you use the right tools and materials (e.g. gas-rated thread tape, etc.) there's probably nothing wrong with that. But IMHO it'd be better to just get whatever the grill manufacturer provides, assuming they do.

Answer (score 0):

If your gas grill connection is really a 3/8 female NPT sized... Then what you need are two pieces. A 3/4" x 3/8" NPT black steel bushing, and a short 3/8" black steel nipple. ( short pipe with male threads on both ends. ) You can get a really short nipple and barely add any length to the output. However, that complicates the install since you won't be able to get a wrench directly on the nipple. I suggest a 3" nipple. It will add about 1.5 inches to the overall length with the bushing.

For something this close to valves, I wouldn't bother with tape, just use the correct pipe dope (sealant) for gas pipes. I recently fell in love with [sealant in small tubes](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RectorSeal-1-75-oz-5-Pipe-Thread-Sealant-25790/100144191)! No brush, no mess.

Leak test with soap once you are done.

[image: Black Steel Bushing]
[image: Black Steel Nipple]