# What is the ideal connection to reduce 3/4" gas pipe to 3/8" gas pipe for a natural gas grill?

Tags: gas, natural-gas

My contractor installed a 3/4" gas line to the exterior of my house, and capped it off, as I didn't know what type of grill I would be purchasing and what connection it would expect. The Weber grill I purchased expects a 3/8" male pipe thread (MIP) to its quick-connect hose.

I went to the hardware store and the helpful person there sold me the pictured series of adapters, but cautioned me against actually using it due to the fact that it's too many adapters chained together. Ideally, I can just find a shutoff valve that has a 3/4" FIP input for my gas line and has a 3/8" MIP output, and I don't need any additional adapters, but digging around on the internet, such a thing doesn't seem to exist. If I need to purchase parts, what's the fewest number possible, and what material should they be? (Brass, I assume, but maybe others are acceptable for outdoor use?)

[image: photo of pipe adapters]

It's worth noting that there [is another similar question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/180393/what-s-the-best-way-to-connect-my-3-4-gas-line-to-my-3-8-grill-hose#comment557495_196929), but it doesn't have an accepted answer, and the highest-voted answer seems to actually be the wrong type of adapter

Comment: It looks to me like [Home Depot has the part you need](https://www.homedepot.com/p/LTWFITTING-3-4-in-x-3-8-in-MIP-Brass-Pipe-Hex-Reducing-Nipple-Fitting-5-Pack-HF306R12605/313805777) to go from the valve to the quick-connect, which reduces the fitting count by one (though that listing is a 5-pack).

Comment: Why would you need two valves? That's what makes the least sense to me. No matter what you need one valve. I'd go with the 3/4 valve then whether you use the 2 adapters in your pic or the one from the answer seems like not a big deal to me. In neither case would I bother with the redundant 3/8 valve.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor, I don't think that's a valve; it looks to me that the yellow part that you're assuming is a handle is a dust cap to cover the quick connect end.

Comment: Correct @spuck, the piece on the right is the quick-connect that came with the grill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the photo, it looks like you need a simple MIP-to-MIP adapter.

From 3/4" to 3/8".

Those exist everywhere like at Home Depot and other places.

[MIP to MIP](https://www.homedepot.com/p/LTWFITTING-3-4-in-x-3-8-in-MIP-Brass-Pipe-Hex-Reducing-Nipple-Fitting-5-Pack-HF306R12605/313805777)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to buy a "gas plug" or "bbq gas outlet" which is the valve and quick connect all preassembled in a metal box with a hinged cover.  They come in different pipe sizes with rear or bottom entry for the gas supply and recessed or surface mount boxes.

Comment: +1.  This is the way to go.  I'll add that the "gas plug" outlets that I've bought usually also contain an automatic safety shutoff (triggered by temperature) in case of fire.

Comment: Something like this? https://mbsturgis.com/products/stainless-steel-gas-outlet-box/

Comment: @swrobel yes!  Or [these](https://bbymfg.com/products/) have more configuration options.

Comment: The "cons" are these are more expensive and a little harder to install.

Comment: @jay613 does Burnaby make on with a 3/4" input & 3/8" output like Sturgis does? I can't find that on their site.

Comment: Idk but they answer questions quickly.  They have a million variations, you almost can't buy without writing them.

Answer (score 1):

I used a bunch of reducers because that's what was readily available at the store. Some day I'll order a 3/4"->3/8" reducer from the Internet but today is not that day.

One thing to note is that the coupling most certainly corrodes over time. Mine is about 2 years old and is ready for replacement. Disconnecting and reconnecting the hose is now very cumbersome.

[image]

---

> cautioned me against actually using it due to the fact that it's too many adapters chained together

Meh. Just don't jostle it or be too rough when disconnecting/reconnecting. I hope the helpful associate also sold you some teflon gas tape or pipe dope.

Comment: Thanks! They did include pipe dope

Comment: @swrobel Nice! So what route did you end up taking?

Comment: I ended up using [this adapter](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00XZWFWCQ) suggested by @Ruskes

Comment: @swrobel Nice, I couldn't justify buying the 5-pack so I never bought it, hah